# git commit error - cannot run vim: No such file or directory

Tags: git, vi

```
$ git commit  
error: cannot run vim: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor 'vim'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

How can I overcome the error and define the editor?

Comment: Do you want to run vim or some other editor? If you want to run vim, does it work if you run it from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

as it was a new machine and vim wasn't installed.

Comment: Couldn't "the answer" also have been `export EDITOR=vi`?

Answer (score 16):

Besides installing `vim` or specifying the commit message on the command-line like the error message suggested, there are several ways to tell git which editor it should use. You can set the `core.editor` property (locally for that project, or globally for all of git):

```
$ git config --global core.editor nano
```

You can also set the `EDITOR` environment variable, which git will fall back on if `core.editor` isn't set:

```
$ export EDITOR=nano
```